# No internet after disabling and enabling wifi

Tags: networking, internet

Yesterday, I noticed that my computer's (Ubuntu 18.04 lts) internet does not work after closing it (letting it go to sleep) and reopening it. This problem also happens if I just disable and reenable wifi. Restarting does fix this problem, but only until I disconnect from the wifi again. I know this is not a problem with my router as another Ubuntu 18.04 machine works fine with the same wifi. An interesting property of this problem is that the wifi shows as connected, but no internet is present.

I have tried everything I could find, such as `sudo service network-manager restart`, disabling IPv6, and adding 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to my wifi's DNS option. None of these worked. In addition, `rfkill list` shows all of my connections as not being blocked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` returns

```
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4010]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at ed400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer will get you going again but does not address the sleep/suspend problem.
At a teminal type `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`
to detemine the driver and module name of your network card.
You will see it next to... Kernel Driver in use: **or** Kernel modules:
Now you know the name of the module type `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi`
Wait 5 seconds and type `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` (editied after discovering module name).

Comment: That command returns `iwlwifi` being my kernel driver. The latter two commands do not, however, make my wifi start working again.
Also, I've noticed that while my wifi isn't working, the `sudo` command takes much longer to run than it does normally. Perhaps that could be something related to this problem?

Comment: Well that sux. Look in /lib/firmware and see if there is specific firmware for your harware (would have shown up with the lspci command) so let us know the exact hardware that it showed i.e RTL8111 or whatever brand. Doing a `sudo apt-get update` then reboot is always good after upgrade issues too.

Comment: What exactly am I looking for here? I see a lot of .ucode files starting with "iwlwifi" in /lib/firmware, is that the right thing? There's also a mwlwifi folder, but I doubt that's the right thing.

Comment: From your `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` which you should have posted for everyone to read, it will show your network card. Could be realtek, broadcom, intel, whatever. And have a relating number. We need to confirm that you have a driver and firmware installed for your specifi network card. So find out what network adapter you have.

Comment: I have edited my original post with the output of the above lspci command. `lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|internet'`, another command I found that returns the controller name, gave an output of "Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)".

Comment: Looks like it's missing the line above "Subsystem:" Mine looks like this; 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4464] (rev 03)

Comment: How would I fix this?

Comment: Again not a solution but this might get it going again `nmcli nm wifi off`
and the try `nmcli nm wifi on`

Comment: `nmcli nm wifi off` tells me that the argument nm is not understood. Am I messing up the syntax somehow?

Comment: My bad it's **r** instead of **nm** so `nmcli r wifi on`